# Query update and variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to get result of a file then put it in a query:

The file content: `test9`

And when I `echo $content` it gives `test9`.

But the problem in the query is that it gives the last character of the content:

```
update code set code ='9' where id_prof= 1
```

PHP code:

```
if(is_file($chemin))

{  include("../../connexion/connexion.php");
    $connexion = new class_connect();
       $cn = $connexion->connect(null);
        $content = readfile($chemin);
    echo $content;

      $id_prof = $_SESSION["id_prof"];
      $query = $cn->prepare("update code set code ='$content' where id_prof= $id_prof ");
      print_r($query);
//        $query->execute();
}
```

The table code in database is like this:

> code :  TEXT : 500,
>
> id_prof : INT :50

Please help me and thank you.

Comment: Wthat is the output of: `$sql = "update code set code ='$content' where id_prof= $id_prof "; echo $sql;`

Comment: update code set code ='9' where id_prof= 1

Comment: explain : `it give the last caracter of content`

Comment: $content = test9  but when i write echo $query it give

Comment: update code set code ='9' where id_prof= 1    u can see here that $content =9 last caracter

Comment: it is fine for me in my localhost,once try like this `code set code ='{$content}'`

Comment: i dont work for me :/

Comment: but the problem with the content which had type TEXT not the id_prof INT

Comment: BTW, INT(50) is meaningless. In the absence of a ZEROFILL, INT(11) is meaningless too. There's just INT, TINYINT, and BIGINT. Similarly, TEXT(500) is meaningless too. You probably meant VARCHAR(500)!.. And how did ravinder's inverted commas disappear?

Comment: no i put text because sometimes the content will be variable which there's lot of text

Comment: what do you meant by ravinder's !

Comment: @saganeo: With the available info posted, it is not predictable on the said output issue. When using `prepare`, why don't you use placeholder to bind value. Check in that way and see if the result differs. `$query = $cn->prepare( "update code set code =? where id_prof= $id_prof" ); $query->bind_param( "s", $content ); $query->execute();` And see if proper value is set in database.

Comment: The return value of `readfile` is **not** the content of the given file but the numbers of bytes read. What happens when you replace `readfile` by `file_get_contents`?